# How can I change an existing windows explorer path?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++

I'm using `VC++6.0, XP system.`

I have an existing windows explorer, folder path `"C:\ "` for example. 
How can I change its path to `"D:\ "` in the same window??

I can find this window handle by using FindWindow function. Does it help?

Comment: Do you mean, for example there's a Windows Explorer window already opened which points to the C:\ folder and you would like your application to somehow make it display the D:\ folder instead?

Comment: I think he means he wants to obtain the handle for an Explorer window and navigate it to a different folder.

Comment: Isn't that what I said?

Comment: I'm guessing this is the proper way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775113(v=vs.85).aspx. [This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/10/10424662.aspx) might help in getting the `IShellBrowser`.

Comment: You can try the undocumented `CWM_SETPATH` message: http://koti.mbnet.fi/vaultec/files/miscellaneous/undocw95/cabmsgs.html

Comment: @JonathanPotter, [What an article!](http://i.imgur.com/q3S0iIx.png)

Comment: @chris: Weird, [maybe try a new browser](http://i.imgur.com/mRj0Cav.png) ;)

Comment: @JonathanPotter, AFAIK, I have the newest version of Chrome :p

Comment: Borgleader, yes. that's what i'm trying to do. I don't want a new window to display. I just want the current existing window to browser a new path.

Comment: Chris, can you give me a code example? It seems like what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to use it. The first parameter of the function, PCUIDLIST_RELATIVE pidl, what's that and how can I pass that?